# difference between LOAD_RCPP_MODULE and Rcpp::InternalFunction

Tags: c++, rcpp, rinside

What is the difference between `Rcpp::InternalFunction` and  `LOAD_RCPP_MODULE` in the context of using RInside? They seem to have the same purpose just `LOAD_RCPP_MODULE` has an extra layer. What are the use cases for both of them and when should i prefer one over the other?

```
//example with LOAD_RCPP_MODULE
const char* hello( std::string who ){
    std::string result( "hello " ) ;
    result += who ;
    return result.c_str() ;
} 

RCPP_MODULE(bling){
    using namespace Rcpp ;
    function( "hello", &hello );
}

R["bling"] = LOAD_RCPP_MODULE(bling);
```

Here is the other example

```
//example with Rcpp::InternalFunction
  const char* hello( std::string who ){
        std::string result( "hello " ) ;
        result += who ;
        return result.c_str() ;
    } 

R["hello"] = Rcpp::InternalFunction( &hello )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules would let you expose several functions and classes. `InternalFunction` only exposes one function at a time.

`InternalFunction` is something of a curiosity, that we added at some point to answer a "can we do that" type of question. It is one of these things that stay in Rcpp because they once were, but that does not get too much attention from us. It is mostly used in `RInside` to allow R code to call c++ functions. This is a curious pattern given that with `RInside` the focus is a C++ application embedding R.

Modules however, do get a lot of attention. My advice would be to use them.

Comment: true I agree with your comments, there are some use cases of `InternalFunction`, for example a function in C++ passed to an R optimization library but its definitely not a show stopper if you avoid `InternalFunction`.

Comment: Sure. I know it is useful, otherwise I would not have put it in. If your objective function is a c++ function, I guess I'd look into optimization algorithms that don't need to go back to R to call it... so have it all in C++

Answer (score 1):

"It depends."

These are different tools for similar purposes. Note the "Internal" though which signals something.  In general, Modules are a very fine and powerful too for Rcpp (with their own vignette) and also accessible via RInside.